# ng-switch doesn't work inside ng-repeat AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have some troubles with my code.
I am trying to develop a questionnaire app that will have only 5 questions with 4 variants of answers on each.
I used `ng-switch` inside `ng-repeat`, but it doesn't work.

P.S. It's only educational project.

There are index.html and app.js:

```js
const testApp = angular.module('tespApp',[]);
testApp.controller('testAppCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.tasks = [
        {id: '1', question1: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', question2: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', question3: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', question4: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'},
        {id: '2', question1: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', question2: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', question3: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', question4: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'},
        {id: '3', question1: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', question2: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', question3: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', question4: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'},
        {id: '4', question1: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', question2: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', question3: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', question4: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'},
        {id: '5', question1: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', question2: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', question3: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', question4: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'},
    ];
    $scope.left = $scope.tasks.length;
    $scope.taskNow = $scope.tasks[0].id;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="tespApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="testAppCtrl">
    <h1>Тест</h1>
    <h2>Осталось вопросов: {{left}}</h2>
    <h3>Вопрос: №{{taskNow}}</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="task in tasks">
        <div ng-switch-on="task.id">
            <div ng-switch-when="1">1</div>
            <div ng-switch-when="2">2</div>
            <div ng-switch-when="3">3</div>
            <div ng-switch-when="4">4</div>
            <div ng-switch-when="5">5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying just to list tasks with variants?

Comment: In the beginning, yes, but then it will be necessary to display in the end all the answers that have been selected

Comment: Here is the working [js-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maxisam/NgFcn/). This will solve your problem! Thanks

Comment: Ok, it`s working, but WHY my code doesn`t work ?) I can`t understand this logic :)

Answer (score 2):

you wrote:

> ```
> <div ng-switch-on="task.id">
> ```

But it should be:

```
<div ng-switch on="task.id">
```